# Best way to group_by inside a rolling in polars?

Tags: python-polars

Given a dateset that looks like this where each node has one row per hour.  Bid type is simply a calculated column where values greater than 5 is Buy, less than 2 is Sell, otherwise it's None.

|  | Node | date | Hour | Price | BidType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1349561 | N001 | 2020-12-13 00:00:00 | 17 | 30.63 | Buy |
| 391333 | CE | 2020-12-17 00:00:00 | 13 | -2.42 | Sell |
| 784166 | N002 | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 14 | -0.92 | Sell |
| 1191909 | MMM | 2020-12-14 00:00:00 | 21 | -1.69 | Sell |
| 44068 | MMS | 2020-12-08 00:00:00 | 4 | 2.07 | None |

In polars, I want to do a rolling average of the price, but grouped by Node, Hour and BidType.  So let's say for date 2020-12-13, for Node N001 for Hour 17, for BidType='Buy', I want to take the last 100 days and take the mean of all the rows that correspond to Node=N001, Hour=17 and BidType='Buy' and calculate the mean price.  Do that for all combination of Node, Hour, BidType...

My first instinct was to do:

```
.rolling('date', period='100d', by=['Node', 'Hour', 'BidType']).agg(pl.col('Price').mean())
```

but it doesn't work.  It returns only 24 rows per date per node...  But I would expect it to have 3 * 24 rows per node since there's 3 possible BidType * 24 hours for each node.

Another try would be:

```
.rolling('date', period='10d', by=['Node', 'Hour'])
    .agg(
        pl.col('Price').filter(pl.col('BidType') == 'Buy').mean().alias('Price_buy'),
        pl.col('Price').filter(pl.col('BidType') == 'Sell').mean().alias('Price_sell'),
        pl.col('Price').filter(pl.col('BidType') == 'None').mean().alias('Price_none')
    )
    .melt(['Node', 'Hour', 'date'])
```

But this doesn't seem to return what I want either.

What is the recommended way of doing what I want?

Here is some code to generate a dataset to test the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(24*10*100, 1)), columns=['Price'])
df['Node'] = np.concatenate([np.repeat(np.arange(0, 10), 24) for x in range(0, 100)])
df['date'] = np.concatenate([pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=24, freq='D') for x in range(0,100*10)])
df['Hour'] = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, 24) for x in range(0, 100*10)])
df['Time'] = df.date + pd.to_timedelta(df.Hour, unit='h')

df = pl.DataFrame(df)
df = df.sort('date', 'Hour')
df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('Price') >= 5).then(pl.lit('Buy')).otherwise(pl.when(pl.col('Price') < 2).then(pl.lit('Sell')).otherwise(pl.lit('None'))).alias('BidType'))
df
```

Comment: Can you provide a `df = pl.DataFrame(...)` line to make your dataset reproducible?

Comment: @BallpointBen I added some code sample to generate data for that.

Comment: " It returns only 24 rows per date per node... But I would expect it to have 3 * 24 rows per node since there's 3 possible BidType * 24 hours for each node."  `.rolling` returns as many rows as in the original, are you looking for a solution where you want it every hour regardless of the input dataframe? If so, `group_by_dynamic` probably does what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the example clear, I am working with a much smaller dataframe. You can find the code to generate the dataframe at the end of the question.

```
shape: (8, 4)
┌──────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ node ┆ date                ┆ price ┆ bid_type │
│ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ str      │
╞══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ null     │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 0     ┆ Sell     │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 3     ┆ null     │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 3     ┆ null     │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 7     ┆ Buy      │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 9     ┆ Buy      │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 3     ┆ null     │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ null     │
└──────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

As you can see, the dataframe contains data for only 2 nodes, 2 days, and 2 hours per day.

**Problem diagnostics.** [`pl.DataFrame.rolling`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html) will, for each row in the dataframe, create a look-back window of length `period` that contains all rows matching the current rows' `by` values.

Especially, in the example above, there won't be a row for `node == "a"`, `date == 2021-01-01 00:00:00`, and `bid_type == "Buy"`, as there is no corresponding row in the original dataframe. Therefore, naively applying `pl.DataFrame.rolling().agg()` will produce the following windows.

```
shape: (8, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ node ┆ hour ┆ bid_type ┆ date                ┆ price     │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ i8   ┆ str      ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ list[i64] │
╞══════╪══════╪══════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [5]       │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [0]       │
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [5, 3]    │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [3]       │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [7]       │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [9]       │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [3]       │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [5]       │
└──────┴──────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

**Answer.** To achieve the desired effect, you can create a new dataframe, which for each `node`, `date`, `bid_type` combination has a corresponding row. `price` in the new dataframe is missing if and only if the original dataframe did not contain the given combination.

```py
# create dense dataframe
skeleton = (
    df
    .select(pl.col("node").unique())
    .join(df.select("date").unique(), how="cross")
    .join(df.select("bid_type").unique(), how="cross")
    .sort("node", "date", "bid_type")
)

# join with original prices
skeleton.join(df, on=["node", "date", "bid_type"], how="left", join_nulls=True)
```

```
shape: (24, 4)
┌──────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ node ┆ date                ┆ bid_type ┆ price │
│ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪═════════════════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ 5     │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ 0     │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ 3     │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ 3     │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ 7     │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ 9     │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ 3     │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ null     ┆ 5     │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
└──────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

Applying [`pl.DataFrame.rolling`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html) produces the desired rolling windows.

```py
(
    skeleton
    .join(df, on=["node", "date", "bid_type"], how="left", join_nulls=True)
    .rolling(
        index_column="date",
        period="2d",
        by=["node", pl.col("date").dt.hour().alias("hour"), pl.col("bid_type")],
    )
    .agg(
        pl.col("price")
    )
    .sort("node", "date", "bid_type")
)
```

*Note.* Use `pl.col("price").mean()` in the aggregation to obtain the rolling average instead of the rolling windows.

```
shape: (24, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ node ┆ hour ┆ bid_type ┆ date                ┆ price        │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---                 ┆ ---          │
│ str  ┆ i8   ┆ str      ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ list[i64]    │
╞══════╪══════╪══════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════╡
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [5]          │
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [0]          │
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [5, 3]       │
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [null, null] │
│ a    ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [null, null] │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [null, 3]    │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [null, null] │
│ a    ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [0, null]    │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [7]          │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [9]          │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [null]       │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [null, 3]    │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [7, null]    │
│ b    ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [null, null] │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [null, 5]    │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [9, null]    │
│ b    ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ [null, null] │
└──────┴──────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

**Sanity check.** As a sanity check, we can set `N_NODES = 1`, `N_DAYS = 365`, and `N_HOURS = 1` in the code for data generation and also set `period="365d"` in the call to `pl.DataFrame.rolling`. This will ensure, that the rolling windows of later timestamps contain sufficiently many data points to obtain reasonable monte-carlo estimates. We get price means of around `0.5`, `3.5`, and `7.5` for windows of bid type `"Sell"`, `None`, and `"Buy"`, respectively. This nicely matches the expected value of a discrete uniform distribution supported on `{0, 1}`, `{2, 3, 4, 5}`, and `{6, 7, 8, 9}`.

**Code for data generation.**

```py
import string
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

N_NODES = 2
N_DAYS = 2
N_HOURS = 2

# create df of unique nodes
df_nodes = pl.DataFrame({"node": list(string.ascii_letters[:N_NODES])})

# create df of unique dates
df_dates = (
    pl.DataFrame({
        "date": pl.datetime_range(
            pl.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
            pl.datetime(2021, 1, 1).dt.offset_by(f"{N_DAYS}d").dt.offset_by("-1h"),
            interval="1h",
            eager=True,
        )
    })
    .filter(pl.col("date").dt.hour() < N_HOURS)
)

# create df of all node / date combinations
df = df_nodes.join(df_dates, how="cross")

# add random price and bid type
df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.lit(np.random.randint(0, 10, df.height)).alias("price"),
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.coalesce(
            pl.when(pl.col("price") > 5).then(pl.lit("Buy")),
            pl.when(pl.col("price") < 2).then(pl.lit("Sell")),
        ).alias("bid_type")
    )
)
df

# create df of unique nodes
df_nodes = pl.DataFrame({"node": list(string.ascii_letters[:N_NODES])})

# create df of unique dates
df_dates = (
    pl.DataFrame({
        "date": pl.datetime_range(
            pl.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
            pl.datetime(2021, 1, 1).dt.offset_by(f"{N_DAYS}d").dt.offset_by("-1h"),
            interval="1h",
            eager=True,
        )
    })
    .filter(pl.col("date").dt.hour() < N_HOURS)
)

# create df of all node / date combinations
df = df_nodes.join(df_dates, how="cross")

# add random price and bid type
df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.lit(np.random.randint(0, 10, df.height)).alias("price"),
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.coalesce(
            pl.when(pl.col("price") > 5).then(pl.lit("Buy")),
            pl.when(pl.col("price") < 2).then(pl.lit("Sell")),
        ).alias("bid_type")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Next to my alternative solution based on the creation of a  *dense* dataframe, I've also implemented your second approach, which should also work.

```py
(
    df
    .rolling(
        index_column="date", period="100d",
        by=["node", pl.col("date").dt.hour().alias("hour")],
    )
    .agg(
        pl.col("price").filter(pl.col("bid_type") == "Buy").mean().alias("Buy"),
        pl.col("price").filter(pl.col("bid_type").is_null()).mean().alias("None"),
        pl.col("price").filter(pl.col("bid_type") == "Sell").mean().alias("Sell"),
    )
    .melt(
        id_vars=["node", "date", "hour"],
        variable_name="bid_type", value_name="price",
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("bid_type").replace("None", None)
    )
    .sort("node", "date", "bid_type")
)
```

The following output was obtained with the example data generated in my other answer.

```
shape: (24, 5)
┌──────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ node ┆ date                ┆ hour ┆ bid_type ┆ price │
│ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i8   ┆ str      ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 5.0   │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ 0.0   │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 4.0   │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 3.0   │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ null  │
│ a    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ 0.0   │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ 7.0   │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ 9.0   │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ null     ┆ 3.0   │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Buy      ┆ 7.0   │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ null     ┆ 5.0   │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Buy      ┆ 9.0   │
│ b    ┆ 2021-01-02 01:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ Sell     ┆ null  │
└──────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴──────────┴───────┘
```